# Website and in particular divs are behaving differently when hosted

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

The divs are stacking and taking up 100% width and others are being ignored entirely (namely the main wrapper which makes the entire page width="960px" is being completely ignored).

[How the page looks when opened in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF8QF.png)

[How the image looks like hosted at uhostfull.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N0Qq.png)

As you can see my games section (admins choice) has jumped into the advert space despite each section sitting inside a div class .container.

```
.container {
position: static;
float: left;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Another thing that is occurring is that the main div I have used to manage the page div id #page-wrap is not doing its job:

```
#page-wrap {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I should also mention that any divs that I create and test in chrome work (say if I make a few white boxes for example) but they will not show up when I host!

My main concern is somehow stopping the advert space automatically adopting the games section as a parent div without being nested.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="playpar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="playpar.js" async></script>

    <title>Website name
    </title>

    <title>
        Curveball Adrenaline Challenge Bubble Trouble
    </title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrap">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="sitelogo"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/Logo%20bling_zpsikvjtrrl.jpg"/></a></div>
        <div id="sitebold"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-09%20at%2022.45.36_zpsx5p40xx4.png"/></a></div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="advertspace"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/whitetile_zpswxxr0bja.png" class="filler"><p class="getme">Advertise here</p></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Administrator's Picks</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="games">
                    <a href="/curveballthegame"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/Curveball%20image_zpscalom4mw.png" class="games"/>
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text"><span>Curve Ball</span></div></div></div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="games">
                    <a href="/adrenalinechallenge"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/Adrenaline%20challenge%20image_zpsyinfiyue.jpg" class="games"/>
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text"><span>Adrenaline Challenge</span></div></div></div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="games">
                    <a href="/bubbletrouble"><img src="http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f50/giansonn/Bubble%20trouble%20image_zpsy3mnffrg.png" class="games"/>
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text"><span>Bubble Trouble</span></div></div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>

    <div id="footnavbox"><a href="https://www.Webname.com" class="footnavigator">Home</a> | <a href="https://www.Webname.com/imageboard" class="footnavigator">Image Board</a> | <a href="https://www.Webname.com/contactus" class="footnavigator">Contact us</a></div>

</div>

</body>
```

I think all these issues are related, help is appreciated.

Comment: You've only linked images. Code would be easier to debug. Are you certain that the CSS is uploaded, and accessible? Any 404s in your console?

Comment: I haven't tried debugging... I am using textwrangler and uploading from there using file manager

Comment: Try visiting the hosted version, in Chrome, and use ctrl-shift-i to open the dev tools. Select the console tab, and look for any errors you might be getting.

Comment: nothing, just the missing .js file which I haven't made yet.